# running cobol in visual studio code problem with json file

Tags: json, cobol

I'm trying to compile cobol code in vs studio code, but got problem with the json file, see:
https://dickens.co.in/run-cobol-vscode-msys2-windows

below is the json file:

The problem is the row with - "cobcargs": ,
how to fix this?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
        {
            "name": "COBOL debugger",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "cobcargs": ,
            "group": ["${file}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your JSON file is that the "cobcargs" value is empty

The "cobcargs" field is used to pass arguments to the compiler. You should specify the necessary compiler arguments

here's an example with arguments

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "COBOL debugger",
      "type": "gdb",
      "request": "launch",
      "cobcargs": ["-free"],  // Specify the compiler arguments here
      "group": ["${file}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: but i dont know any arguments, and the owner of the webpage doesnt answer

Comment: The "cobcargs" field is used to pass arguments to the COBOL compiler. You should specify the necessary compiler arguments within the square brackets after "cobcargs". For example, if you want to pass the -free flag to the COBOL compiler, your JSON file should look like this:

Comment: Most programs just compile without additional arguments... and if you think you need to specify some, then the most reasonable thing to check is the GnuCOBOL manual, no?